# How to sort a column with $ and ',' '.' sign bash command line?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file, and i want to use something like "Cat" command on that file which print out the sorted list.
For example a column loooks like This

```
Mike  $1.00
Mason $1,000,000.00
Tyler $100,000.00
Nick  $0.10
```

Result

```
Nick  $0.10
Mike  $1.00
Tyler $100,000.00
Mason $1,000,000.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
sort -t$ -nk2 fileName
```

Description :

```
 -t$  : use $ as separator
 -nk2 : sort using numbers in column 2
```